# To find the lowest supplier who gives the lowest price

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a sheet that gives the lowest price among two suppliers. And one member from this platform helped me to find which supplier gives the lowest price. but the problem is it displays the value only if both barcode comes in the same row. pls help me to expand this equation that where ever matching barcode comes in the sheet must give me the lowest supplier. Am sorry for my bad english. so that the sheet is shared here. Please take a look.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AscLCZPEv6uHJkgr2KkLJ7V_w7GfySV_19-eiQQ7Sx8/edit#gid=1464637808

Comment: Arya, I don't think you're starting from the right point.  In your other question, you had a much better data structure.  I don't think it will be possible to give you a good answer when your data looks like in your sample sheet.  Why don't you share the way your data really looks, more like the "Supplier A Sale Track" tab in your last sample.  You are just showing a small sample table, and any formula we come up with won't work with your real data.  We need to see the sheet that has your IMPORTDATA formulas, to build an answer based on your actual data structures.

Comment: The formulas in columns J and K don't give correct results at all.  They only seem to work because of the very limited data table you are giving.  We really need to see your real data structure, or I don't think we can help you.  You say you may have 50+ suppliers, and thousands of products.  We need to see how that data is structured.

Comment: @kirkg13 can u pls share your mail address or whatsapp number ? so that i can share u

Comment: @kirkg13 i want one more final edit in our sheet that i want to display the value in another sheet by your solution. so that when we enter a code it must search from the last sheet and generate value. pls check https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1erLJcFbtZDEMkWElwM4heVUh9Dvn0KnveTySRf480tA/edit#gid=419148797

Comment: Arya, this isn't working the way you expect.  Unless you are able to share a SAMPLE COPY of your primary data sheet, which you told me uses IMPORTRANGE formulas, I don't think I can help you get the result you want.  Your "sample" table of data is not sufficient.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [To display which supplier gives the lowest price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62761526/to-display-which-supplier-gives-the-lowest-price)

Answer (score 0):

To get **lowest price** you can use [MIN()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094017?hl=en), example `=MIN(B2, D2)` :
[image]

For the **K2** you already have the formula which works well

`=INDEX(A$1:D$1,match(J2,A2:D2,0)-1)`

And now you select cells J2 + K2 and just drag down to expand it.

[image]

Comment: Jeff, I've spent some time on this, and he wants the last price from each supplier, and then to pick the lowest price from that subset.  The problem is his data structure seems, to me, to be a mess.  Up to 50+ suppliers, in parallel columns.  So I haven't been able to structure a query to find the bottom price, matching that product code, searching an unknown number of columns.  He has't shared his raw data page, which uses IMPORTRANGEs, so I haven't been able to work with the basic data.  I'm about ready to give up.  His sample table, which I helped on, is not yet working the way he expects.

Comment: The latest prices for each supplier are always towards the bottom of the list.  If his basic raw data includes any date info, this would be easy.If we could vertically stack all of the data, to find the bottom price from each supplier, it would be possible.  But with an unknown number of colums on his "production" page, coming up with a generic formula here that could be transferred to his production page, which I think looks quite different, is perhaps beyond my abilities.